# Nestable jQuery plugin - disable dragging between lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I would like to disable dragging between two lists in jQuery nestable plugin.

There is an option **group** in documentation
https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable

group group ID to allow dragging between lists (default 0)

So I change that to element id

```
$('.dd').nestable({
    maxDepth: 1,
    group: $(this).attr('id')
});
```

But it's not working. User can drag and drop items between two nestables as he wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your current code, `this` refers to the parent scope, somethings like `window` or `document`, not `.dd`.

You have to call nestable for each list, try this:

```
$('.dd').each(function(){
    $(this).nestable({
        maxDepth: 1,
        group: $(this).prop('id')
    });
});
```